# C++ template combined with STL return types

Tags: c++, templates, stl, dictionary, overloading

I've a templatized class

```
template <typename T>
class Factors
{
    public:
    Factors(){};
    deque<string> stringsDeck;

    // some methods and variables here
   map <string, string> getNext();
};
```

The `getNext` method combines a string used as key with the strings from `stringsDeck` used as value and returns a `map <string,string>`.
Provided that I have templatized `stringify` and `string2num` functions, I would like to have a method `map<string,Scalar> getNext()` which for every other type except from string acts converting the values of the map to the specified template type `T`.

The compiler doesn't let me overload two methods with the same name but with different return type, specifically:

```
map <string, T > getNext()
{
// converts the values of getNext() return map into the specified type T
return convertedMapWithValuesOfTypeT;
}
```

What can be the solution in this case? I would like to keep the name of the method the same for string and other types (basically numerical types which can be converted from string via a lexical cast)

Comment: So how will you specify whether you want `map<string, string>` or `map<string, T>` when calling `getNext()`? Or do you mean that you want `map<string, T>` if those two functions are defined for `T` (where `T` is parameter of the enclosing class template) and `string` otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The language doesn't allow function overloads which differ only on
return type, because in most cases, the return type isn't considered in
function overload resolution.  In this case, you really have three
possible solutions:

- The simplest (and therefore the preferred solution in most cases) is
  just to give the two functions different names:
  `getNextAsMapToType` and
  `getNextAsMapToString`, for example.
- Alternatively, you could declare the function a template:

  ```
  template<typename U>
  std::map<string, U> getNext();
  ```

  then, specialize this function for `std::string` and
  `T` (and for
  nothing else).  The user will have to specify
  `getNext<std::string>()`
  or `getNext<...>` to call the one he wants.
  Generally, I would find this considerably less readable than the
  previous solution, but it might be applicable in templates, where
  the names should contain or at least suggest the name of the type.
- Finally, it _is_ possible to simulate overloading on the return
  type, if you don't mind some extra complexity.  To do this, you still
  have to implement one of the other solutions, but the client code
  doesn't see it.  Basically, your `getNext()` function must return a
  proxy, with overloaded conversion functions, something like:

  ```
  class Proxy
  {
      Factors* myOwner;
  public:
      Proxy( Factors& owner ) : myOwner( &owner ) {}
      operator std::map<std::string, std::string>() const
      {
          return myOwner->getNextAsMapToString();
      }
      operator std::map<std::string, T>() const
      {
          return myOwner->getNextAsMapToType();
      }
  };

  Proxy getNext() { return Proxy( *this ); }
  ```

  Client code can then just call `getNext()`, and depending on what they
  do with the results, either `getNextAsMapToString` or
  `getNextAsMapToType` will be called.

Comment: You posted HTML instead of Markdown, somehow.

Comment: I know I did, since that's the only way to get reasonable formatting.  Anytime I have something a bit complicated, I'll shift to HTML.

Comment: Unfortunately this makes your answer incorrect. You have seemingly overloaded `operator std::map() const` twice, which is what made me snoop in your post.

Comment: I think at the very end the best way is to have two functions with different name, both readable and simple. Maybe the code duplication may hurt a little bit, but IMHO in this case is acceptable...

Comment: @JamesKanze : I personally prefer the templated method, your 2nd suggestion. It reduces the amount on code to write and is the most forward looking.

If written properly, you would have NO code duplication since converting from std::string to whatever templated type could be done with something like boost::lexical_cast.

Comment: @phresnel There is no such thing as an overload of `operator std::map() const`.  `std::map` isn't a type.  There are two distinct overloads, one to `std::map<std::string, std::string>`, and the other to `std::map<std::string, T>`.  These are two unrelated types.  (Unless `T` is `std::string`, in which case he'd need some sort of specialization, regardless of the solution adopted.)

Comment: @linello I pretty much agree, except for special cases.

Comment: @fronsacqc The principal problem with the templated solution is that the client syntax is unusual.  I'd definitely consider it, however, in cases like the one here, where the class itself is a template: given a choice between `obj.getNext<MyType>()` and `obj.getNextInstantiationType()`, the former says clearer what types are involved.  But without knowing the actual use cases, it's hard to say which solution to prefer; I just presented the three I know, so the poster can choose.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Exactly. I realise you haven't checked what you have posted there, otherwise you would have recognized that the template argument lists were missing, because instead of &lt; and &gt; ([Character Entity References](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.2)), you've just used < and > (angle brackets), which is in violation of HTML, which so far you've misunderstood from my comments. Before my correction, it seemed that you've `overloaded operator std::map() const twice`.

Comment: @fronsacqc Yes you're right, I declared the getNextAsString() method as private method, so the client can't notice it and this way helps me keeping things simple for the final user. I'm rewriting from scratch some non-templatized classes I wrote 1 year ago  so I think this is definitely the best way... 
Many thanks to everyone.

Comment: @fronsacqc OK.  I thought I'd checked it, but apparently not.  (I don't like using HTML here, since there is the markup language.  But I couldn't find any other way of preventing the code block from ending the bulleted point.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a runtime-check in `getNext` using [`typeid`]
(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) to see if `T` is a string or not.

Something like:

```
template <typename T>
class Factors
{
    public:
    Factors(){};
    deque<string> stringsDeck;

    // some methods and variables here
    map <string, T> getNext();
    {
        if (typeid(T) == typeid(string))
        {
            // Special handling for strings
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something else for other types
        }
    }
};
```

### Edit

As fschoenm suggests, template specialization is probably better:

```
template <typename T>
class Factors
{
    public:
    Factors(){};

    // some methods and variables here
    map <string, T> getNext();
};


template <>
class Factors<string>
{
    public:
    Factors(){};
    deque<string> stringsDeck;

    // some methods and variables here
    map <string, string> getNext();
};
```

Comment: Why would you do the type check at run-time if you can also provide a template specialization that is evaluated at compile-time?

Comment: If I've understood him correctly, he wants two functions, one which returns a `std::map<std::string, std::string>`, and another which returns a `std::map<std::string, T>`.

Comment: yes, possibly with the same name for retrocompatibility issues.
I was wondering how to achieve that with some template magic...
If this is not possibile, I'll probably change the name of the `map<string,string> getNext()` to `getNextReturnTypeAsString()`

Comment: @linello Did you try the template specialization? The classes will be named the same and the function will be named the same as well. If you want common functionality, and just have the `getNext` method be different, inherit both from a common base class.